# How to double click

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, node-webkit

Using webdriverjs in testing a nodejs app with selenium.  Trying to figure out how to doubleclick.

I try

```
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().
usingServer(server.address()).
withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
build();
...
var v = browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id("claimSubs-" + claimId));
v.click();
v.click();
```

but it doesn't seem to trigger the action on the web page.

Comment: There should be doubleClick method http://webdriver.io/docs.html#doubleClick

Comment: He is using selenium-webdriver. In [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io) there is a doubleClick method as @olyv mentioned.

Comment: @olvy The `webdriverjs` tag is also used for the Selenium JavaScript binding. I've introduced the `webdriver-io` tag to resolve this problem.